# pyspark only escapes the first quote after a backslash from csv

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a csv data in which I've escaped existing backslash characters using another backslash:

```
year,content
2021,"\\"foo\\",bar"
```

I'd like to read it using spark and display the data. The expected data on the dataframe:

```
+----------+--------------+
| year     | content      |
+----------+--------------+
| 2021     | \"foo\",bar  |
+----------+--------------+
```

But when I ran this:

```
schema = StructType(
        [
            StructField("year", IntegerType(), False),
            StructField("content", StringType(), False),
        ]
   )

    df = (
        spark.read.csv(
            f"s3://path/to/csv",
            schema=schema,
            header=True
        )
    )

    df.show(20,False)
```

I'm getting this:

```
+----------+--------------+
| year     | content      |
+----------+--------------+
| 2021     | "\"foo\\"    |
+----------+--------------+
```

Any idea how to handle this properly?

Answer (score 0):

If you can save your data like this (single escape instead of double escape)

```
year,content
2021,"\"foo\", bar"
```

then you can read it as you're doing and the output would be

```
# +----+----------+
# |year|content   |
# +----+----------+
# |2021|"foo", bar|
# +----+----------+
```